# Query related to posting message on facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 2 fan pages. I have access token for both of them with stream_publish, manage_pages and offline_access. I want same message to be posted on both the pages wall. I am able to post it using graph api and php on both the walls using their respective access_token but what I want to do is post on page one wall as second page. How can I do so.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the access token for that user/page to post on the other page:

```
$facebook->api("/$postingpageid?fields=access_token", 'GET', array('access_token' => $useraccesstoken));
```

$postingpageid is the ID of the page you are posting with
$useraccesstoken is the access token of the admin user for that page

Now you got a new access token, post with that access token to your second page and voilá you're posting as the page identified in pastingpageid.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it using graph api?

Comment: This is Graph API, using the Facebook-PHP-SDK. The Graph-URL in there is `graph.facebook.com/postingpageid?fields=access_token&access_token=useraccesstoken`

Comment: When I enter the page id and access token in the above url and paste it in my browser, I get the same page id and access_token that I had entered

Comment: Then just POST to the wall of page2 using the access_token from page 1 using `/$targetpageid/feed` with the accesstoken you aquired for `/$postingpageid?fields=access_token` - The post then should be on targetpage posted by postingpage.